# I set the entire project to the minimum version of iOS 14, but I still get the error 'StateObject' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer

Tags: xcode

I set the entire project to the minimum version of iOS 14, but I still get the error 'StateObject' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer.
I downloaded this project when cloning Git and restored pods.
I changed all the requirements to iOS 16 through a project search.

Comment: There's not enough info to tell for sure what's wrong exactly, but I'd say you missed a place. Maybe it's in an SPM dependency or in one of your targets.

Answer (score 0):

Search the project for: `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`

This is set at the project level, but in recent Xcode, it appears to be a recommended/default for new targets.

Existing targets need to be set by hand (preferably via the UI, but searching for the lines is the fastest way to analyze problem).